# What do the following lines of code mean

Tags: java, android

I am reading about the Android Lifecycle from the Android Developers docs, and in the `onPause()` part there is this following code snippet:

```
public class JavaCameraComponent implements LifecycleObserver {

    ...

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    public void releaseCamera() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Does it mean that there is an activity in the app that starts the camera, and this activity sends an `ON_PAUSE` event to the life-cycle aware component, and only when it receives this event, it will start the camera? (Meaning that the sending activity is currently on paused state, because the camera app is running?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean that there is an activity in the app that starts the
>   camera, and this activity sends an ON_PAUSE event to the life-cycle
>   aware component, and only when it receives this event, it will start
>   the camera?

The code snippet you have provided doesn't mean that when you receive the `Event.ON_PAUSE`, the camera will be started. What it means is, I'am done with camera usage and freeing up the camera for use by other applications.

> and this activity sends an ON_PAUSE

No. These lifecycle events are dispatched from the framework and the Lifecycle class. These events map to the callback events in activities and fragments. You can refer the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) for more details

For the code you have added,it will simply release the camera on `ON_PAUSE` event

Comment: Thank you, so it basically means that my app was using the camera, and then it was paused, so my app tells the system that someone else can use it?

Comment: @TTnote We need to look at complete code to confirm it. But logically guessing, yes, the app might be using the camera and want's to release it in onPause

Comment: Thank you, the thing that was confusing me about this is, that usually when you launch a camera (from your own app), then the activity is paused! (Because camera has its own app and activity) - so for me: My app launches the camera, now the activity of my app is in paused state! (But my app needs to use it, so the camera cannot be freed for use by other apps, but only my app that needs it currently). I hope you understand what my confusion is all about

Comment: @TTnote This code must be creating its own Camera interface. Its not calling `startActivityForResult()` (which launch camera app and cause your activity to enter paused -> stopped state). Hence, onPause won't be called. Its accessing camera directly and not through "Camera APP"

Comment: Oh! So it's like in WhatsApp for example where they have their own camera activity (With all the editing things, so it's a camera activity that is part of WhatsApp app, not other camera app!)

Comment: @TTnote yeah. Something similar to that. Its part of your app and not 3rd party app.